# Recursive Descent Parser with Indentation and Backtracking

Tags: indentation, recursive-descent

I have been trying to find an Recursive Descent Parser Algorithm that is also suited for indentation with backtracking.
But I keep having myself finding troublesome solutions for this.

Are there any resources out there that also deal with indentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your question I'm assuming that you're writing your own recursive descent parser for an indentation-sensitive language.

I've experimented with indentation-based languages before, and I solved the problem by having a state that keeps track of the current indentation level and two different terminals that match indentation. Both of them match indentation units (say two spaces or a tab) and count them. Let's call the matched indentation level `matched_indentation` and the current indentation level `expected_indentation`.

For the first one, let's call it `indent`:

- if `matched_indentation < expected_indentation`, this is a `dedent`, and the match is a failure.
- if `matched_indentation == expected_indentation`, the match is a success. The matcher consumes the indentation.
- if `matched_indentation > expected_indentation`, you have a syntax error (indentation out of nowhere) and should handle it as such (throw an exception or something).

For the second one, let's call it `dedent`:

- if `matched_indentation < expected_indentation`, the match is successful. You reduce `expected_indentation` by one, but you don't consume the input. This is so that you can chain multiple `dedent` terminals to close multiple scopes.
- if `matched_indentation == expected_indentation`, the match is successful, and this time you do consume the input (this is the last `dedent` terminal, all scopes are closed).

  if `matched_indentation > expected_indentation`, the match simply fails, you don't have a `dedent` here.

Those terminals and non-terminals after which you expect an increase in indentation should increase `expected_indentation` by one.

Let's say that you want to implement a python-like if statement (I'll use EBNF-like notation), it would look something like this:

```
indented_statement : indent statement newline;    

if_statement : 'if' condition ':' newline indented_statement+ dedent ;
```

Now let's look at the following piece of code, and also assume that an `if_statement` is a part of your `statement` rule:

```
1|if cond1:                 <- expected_indentation = 0, matched_indentation = 0
2|  if cond2:               <- expected_indentation = 1, matched_indentation = 1
3|    statement1            <- expected_indentation = 2, matched_indentation = 2
4|    statement2            <- expected_indentation = 2, matched_indentation = 2
5|                          <- expected_indentation = 2, matched_indentation = 0
```

- On the first four lines you'll successfully match an `indent` terminal
- On the last line, you'll match two `dedent` terminals, closing both the scopes, and resulting with `expected_indentation = 0`

One thing you should be careful of is where you put your `indent` and `dedent` terminals. In this case, we don't need one in the `if_statement` rule because it is a `statement`, and `indented_statement` already expects an indent.

Also mind how you treat newlines. One choice is to consume them as a sort of statement terminator, another is to have them precede the indentation, so choose whichever suits you best.